# How to $watch state change of $stateProvider in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I know that I can run:

```
scope.$watch(someItem, function(){})
```

But I can't figure out a way to watch over change of `$state.$current.name` in my application.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

It's in the docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    // do something
})
```

Comment: I should also mention that $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart') must be placed in root state in order to be available in every state change, if i am not misstaken

Comment: I get `Can't find variable: $rootScope` what would I need to do?

Comment: you need to inject the $rootScope into the controller you are calling it in.

Comment: Is there an event like `beforeStateChangeStart` for the rootScope? I'm aware of `ionicView.beforeEnter` but I need something at the global level. Also, correct me plz if I'm wrong in understanding that `stateChangeStart` and `ionicView.beforeEnter` are not similar. What I need is, I need to prevent state navigation at the rootScope in spite of at different controllers. any suggestions?

Comment: @Marcus AFAIK `$stateChangeStart` is the event. calling `event.preventDefault()` would prevent a state change.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but seemingly, `$stateChangeStart` was causing multiple calls to same state loading when a function was wrapped within `$timeout`. Using `$ionicView.beforeEnter` helped perfectly. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: How can I simply use toState? ... I mean I'd like to use it in conjunction with $state.includes('home.specials') ... so something like... if(toState.includes... etc. ... right now I've managed to use it like: if(toState['url'] == '/specials'){...

Comment: @Gabe please update the link to the Angular's docs http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events

Comment: Thanks! This snippet helped me resolve the auth service conundrum I was facing for over a day. Since services are unavailable inside Angular's run()n doing the auth check within a root controller's scope is a great alternative

Comment: $stateChangeStart has been deprecated unfortunately. What now?

Comment: @Diego check out my answer. You can still use $scope.$watch

Answer (score 31):

This works:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $state.$current.name
}, function(newVal, oldVal){
    //do something with values
})
```

Comment: This has helped me with directive implementation. Thanks!

Comment: great use of function as the first $watch arg, i find many devs forget this is an option.