# Observing state changes in angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

As far as I understand, the usual way to get a notification on a state change is to put a callback on the `$stateChangeStart` event, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21867646/42610).

However, if I understand correctly, I could also attach the $state object to the current scope, as in:

```
myApp.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.$state = $state;
}
```

This, as far as I understand, would make it possible to watch state details directly from HTML templates, e.g. (assuming some of my states have a boolean flag `.isAdminOnlyState` set to true and I wanted to make the whole page red when displaying them):

```
<body ng-class='{"everythingInRed": $state.current.data.isAdminOnlyState}'>
```

What are advantages and disadvantages of this approach, as compared to having a listener function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you want to handle something globally or on a single controller/view, the approach you describe is suitable in the case of the latter. However in the code you posted, you need to ensure that `myAppCtrl` is always active in your app for that `ng-class` to be updated correctly. With routing you tend to have a controller(s) active at a given point in time, not all the time. One could argue that this is a disadvantage of the approach you posted, if you handle a `$state` changed event on the `$rootScope` you could put `$state.current.data.isAdminOnlyState` on the `$rootScope` and have it updated accordingly. A disadvantage of putting this on the root scope would be (I imagine) a performance impact, since for every state transition that handler is called, and the code inside the handler is executed, another disadvantage would be that by putting `$state.current.data.isAdminOnlyState` on the `$rootScope` pollutes the root scope which is usually frowned upon. Having said that, if you intend to have `myAppCtrl` active at all times, for example have it be the controller of a section of your main page, such as the navigation bar section for example, it would still be evaluated during every state transition.

Somewhat irrelevant: ui router has a directive to do what you want to that in that code snippet, check out `ui-sref-active`.

Comment: Thank you, that's quite insightful.