# Angular can not auto update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I  wrote an angular project with a navigation bar, I want to the nav bar can auto update when the users had logged in,  so I use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to control it, but the truth is that is no use, what can I do? And have I wrote the wrong code? I don't know could you comprehend my question because I am a Chinese and my English is poor.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
               data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">切换导航</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="index">许愿墙{{username}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a ui-sref="index">首页</a></li>
                <li ng-hide="isLogined"><a ui-sref="user.login">登录</a></li>
                <li ng-show="isLogined"><a ui-sref="user.info">个人中心</a></li>
                <li ng-show="isLogined"><a ui-sref="user.wish">我的愿望</a></li>
                <li ng-show="sex == 'female'"><a ui-sref="user.putwish">许愿</a></li>
                <li ng-show="isLogined"><a ng-click='doLogout()'>注销</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" ui-view>

</div>
```

It's my controller's code:

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'LogoutService', function($scope, $state, LogoutService) {
if(sessionStorage.getItem('username')) {
    $scope.isLogined = true;
    $scope.username = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('sex') == 'male') {
        $scope.sex = 'male';
    } else {
        $scope.sex = 'female';
    }
} else {
    $scope.isLogined = false;
}

$scope.doLogout = function() {
    LogoutService.doLogout();
    sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('sex');
    $state.go('index');
};
}]);
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'LoginService', function($scope, $state, LoginService) {
$scope.doLogin = function() {
    var data = {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
    };
    LoginService.doLogin(data)
        .success(function(data, status){
            if(status === 200) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('username', data.user.username);
                sessionStorage.setItem('sex', data.user.sex);
                $state.go('index');
            }
        });
};
}]);
```

Comment: Usually providing a working codepen / jsfiddle gets you faster answers because people can help you faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread out: [How to $watch state change of $stateProvider in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867569/how-to-watch-state-change-of-stateprovider-in-angularjs)

Create a route change event handler and on route change, call a function in `UserCtrl` controller to check the current login state.

Thus, organize your code as follows:

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', 'LogoutService',
    function($scope, $state, $rootScope, LogoutService) {
        var updateLoginState = function() {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('username')) {
                $scope.isLogined = true;
                $scope.username = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
                if (sessionStorage.getItem('sex') == 'male') {
                    $scope.sex = 'male';
                } else {
                    $scope.sex = 'female';
                }
            } else {
                $scope.isLogined = false;
            }
        };
        $scope.doLogout = function() {
            LogoutService.doLogout();
            sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
            sessionStorage.removeItem('sex');
            $state.go('index');
        };
        //Initially, check the login state when controller initializes
        updateLoginState();
        //Listen to route change and check login state again when route changes
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
            updateLoginState();
        })
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to change your `isLogined` variable to a function:

```
$scope.isLogined = function() { return sessionStorage.getItem('username') !== null; }
```

and then in your view:

```
<li ng-hide="isLogined()">
```

Then do something similar to the sex test

Comment: Yes, I have known what kind of mistake I made, I just only check my variates's changes for once in UserCtrl, I should use a function to check it, thank you very much!