# AngularJS watch value within service

Tags: angularjs, watch, angular-services

I'm currently developing an AngularJS web application.

I have a primary view (Index), child view (Dashboard) and grandchild view (Raiding The Rails).

```
http://localhost:4000/#/dashboard/raiding-the-rails/1
```

Within the grandchild view (Raiding The Rails) I am displaying dress information relevant to the state ID `/1`, each dress has a specified state ID e.g `/1`,`/2`,`/3`.

I have a controller/service sending the state ID to a `console.log` (within the parent) and when viewing `raiding-the-rails/1` the `console.log` displays `{stateID: "1"}`, If I change the URL to `raiding-the-rails/4` the `console.log` doesn't update unless I refresh the page.

Also, When I completely refresh the browser the `console.log` spits out three objects instead of one?

I've reviewed many sites and have tried and tried again trying to figure this out, I even tried setting up a Watch service but this failed massively.

If anyone could help me out I would be highly grateful!
Thank you.

[image: Console.Log]

**App:**

```
(function(angular, undefined){
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting', ['ui.router']);
  am.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard.raidingtherails', {
        url: '/raiding-the-rails',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.raiding-the-rails.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard.raidingtherails.dress', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.raiding-the-rails.dress.html'
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  });
})(angular);
```

**Service:**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting');
  am.factory('raidingService', function () {
    var raidingService = {
      stateID: null
    };
    return raidingService;
  });
})(angular);
```

**Parent Controller:**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting');
  am.controller('dashboardCtrl', function(raidingService) {
    console.log(raidingService);
  });
})(angular);
```

**Child Controller:**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting');
  am.controller('raidingtherailsCtrl', function($state, $stateParams, raidingService) {
    var self = this;
    raidingService.stateID = $stateParams.id;
  });
})(angular);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21867646/1061668

Comment: @MikkoViitala I implemented this but the console.log only show the previous id e.g Start on /3 then go to /6 the console will show id 3 on state change.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's in the parent controller that you want to watch your service?

If so, you could watch a function, like so:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return raidingService.stateId;
}, function(value) {
  console.log(value);
}, true);
```

That should work.

Comment: Evening Lee, Thank you for this! But, it didn't seem to change anything! When changing the state id from /1 to /2 the console log was still spiting out three objects saying stateID: '1' instead of updating and saying stateID: '2'...

Comment: Unless I hard refresh on the new state, the console remains the same! Any further thoughts would help massively!

Comment: If you are getting multiple console logs it looks like your page contains multiple dashboard controls, is that correct? What do your views look like? Any way you can throw it in a JS Bin?

Answer (score 0):

MVC pattern used in any framework:

*You creating `Service` with `.get()` and `.set()` methods. Set method is common to be used in any place you desire to operate `model` value and allows you to create one point that will handle changes to your model. The final move in `.set()` method is `.$boradcast()` notifying whole application about changes to your model.*

Pros:

- one access point to value
- application is know about any changes
- no need to write `$watch` with watching collections (holly-molly)
- having access point to changes with '$on' in your controllers `$scope`

Cons:

- easy to forget to use `.set()` method instead of simple assignment

Comment: Thank you @Appeiron, I'm trying to take this onboard and redevelop what I've done so far! but, struggling...

Comment: In my experience `$watch` is thing that allows you to watch local changes in controller or it's content without moving out. The best way to translate flow of information through application is _event-notification system_

Comment: In your case you just need that `set` and `get` methods with `on` in your controllers.

Comment: Do you have any recommended sites which will advice me on how to use Set, Get and On ?

Comment: Will try to create plunker for ya bud

Comment: Had any luck @Appeiron?

Comment: I've tired and went to sleep so continue tomorrow ;D

Comment: No problem, @Appeiron! Thank you for help anyways and I'll keep an eye-out for your response tomorrow :)