# Trigger event after $state.go()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Is it possible to trigger an event after the state was changed in ui.router? Strictly speaking I am working with ionic framework with angularJS and considering it uses angular-ui-router.

Attention: Pseudo code I'd like to use.

```
$state.go('app.list').then(function(){ DO SOMTHING });
```

It is not state specific. Should be usable for any given state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it directly, as far as I know, however as you can see in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867569/how-to-watch-state-change-of-stateprovider-in-angularjs), you can watch for state change and add your code in there:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
        if (toState == 'app.list') {
            //DO SOMTHING
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Whould you place it in the specific Controller?

Comment: @NEXTLEVELSHIT honestly, I am not sure. Will have to check this.