# Changing state without changing browser history in angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, browser-history

Assume that we have a logic like this:

- From state A, change to state B.
- Whenever we arrive to state B, the app always redirect us to state C by calling `$state.go(stateC)`
- Now we are in state C

My question is how to go back to state A from state C (given the fact that state A can be any state we don't know at run-time, meaning user can access state B from any other states)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the `location` option with value *"replace"*...

```
$state.go(stateC, null, {
    location: 'replace'
})
```

See https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go

> **location** - {boolean=true|string=} - If `true` will update the url in the location bar, if `false` will not. If string, must be `"replace"`, which will update url and also **replace last history record**.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you so so much.

Answer (score -2):

You could keep track of visited states in a service and then just call $state.go on the previous state.

You can watch the state changes like so:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    // add fromState to history 
});
```

[How to $watch state change of $stateProvider in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867569/how-to-watch-state-change-of-stateprovider-in-angularjs)