# ionic 1 - How to enable back button on header - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

When I navigating from home page to another, back button not displaying at the navigation bar. However, there are certain case where ionic display the back button. e.g navigate Settings page form profile page back button display properly and mobile bank button also working fine.

The Goal is user have to go to home page when press mobile hardware back button with display back button on navigation bar and on home page display confirmation when press hardware back button.

I have already searched lots of Q&A over stack but nothing found proper solutions for this.

Here is my code that try to -

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $ionicHistory, $localStorage, $timeout, $http, $state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event) {
            if ($state.current.name=="app.home") {
                $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: 'System',
                    template: 'are you sure you want to exit?'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    if (res) {
                        ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                    }
                })
            }
        }, 101);
    });
})
```

How can I force Ionic to display back button on certain page?

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.settings', {
        cache:false,
        url: '/settings',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/setting/settings.html',
                controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.wfhadd', {
        cache:false,
        url: '/wfh/wfhadd',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/wfh/addwfh.html',
                controller: 'AddWfhCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.wfhlist', {
        cache:false,
        url: '/wfh/wfhlist',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/wfh/wfhlist.html',
                controller: 'listWfhCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.login', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/login/:userid/:logpass',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                params:  {'userid': null, 'logpass': null}
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.profile', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/settings/profile',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/setting/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.activities', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/activities',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/activities.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.leave', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/leave',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/leave/leave.html',
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.leavelist', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/leave/allleaves/:id',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/leave/leavelist.html',
                controller: 'LeaveCtrl',
                params:  {'leaveid': null}
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.leavedtls', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/leave/details',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/leave/leavedtls.html',
                controller: 'LeaveDtlsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.leaveapply', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/leave/apply',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/leave/leaveapply.html',
                controller: 'LeaveApplyCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.terms', {
        url: '/settings/terms',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/policy.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.about', {
        url: '/settings/about',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/about.html'
            }
        }
    })
    ;
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
})
```

**EDIT 1**

Now I have put following code on profile controller and back button show on Profile page but It's not working (not go back to home page).

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope, $ionicHistory, $http,$localStorage, $ionicNavBarDelegate){

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
        viewData.enableBack = true; 
    });

})
```

Comment: Did you try to use `$stateChangeStart` event? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867569/how-to-watch-state-change-of-stateprovider-in-angularjs

Comment: Where need to push it? any example @ Tan

Comment: You can add it in your main controller, to make sure this event is always be registered.

Comment: Fine. then how to enable back button by using this?

Comment: You can use the same function `$stateChangeStart`. I supposed

Comment: Never mind - any working example would be best..

Comment: you can see back button for child views from the root only. Setting page is the root the page that nested to settings can only see the back button

Comment: When I navigate to settings page form side menu - no back button on header. Seems all page looks like. @ Abinesh

Comment: in setting page you can see only menu button in header. Because setting is the root of the state. you can see back button in setting nested pages

Comment: yeah. But I want to show back button over there. That my goal.

Comment: Then create a back button in templates menu.html and give root condition for that settings page

Comment: Thanks any example?@Abinesh

Comment: I provided an example pls check it and reply